how to search with two or more keywords in nestjs typeorm & postgresql
first my english is like a babys walking .
I need help to the nestjs typeorm querybuilder.
I has 2 tables and 1 join table.

cards
id, content, writer, pickers

tags
id, keyword

cards tags (join table)
cardsId, tagsId


2 columns is join columns in cards table.

writer(id, name)
pickers(id)

i need search cards by keyword in tag

can select many tags.
if select many tags -> "AND"

my code was get rows by 1 single tag keyword.
if select many to 2 tags, this code was not working. T.T
how i fix this code?
+
i need only get COUNT from pickers.
my curr builder code
.createQueryBuilder('card')
      .innerJoin('card.tags', 'tags')
      .leftJoin('card.writer', 'writer')
      .leftJoin('card.pickers', 'pickers')
      .where('tags.keyword IN (:...keywords)', { keywords: keywordList })
      .having('COUNT(DISTINCT tags.keyword) = :count', {
        count: keywordList.length,
      })
      .groupBy('card.id')
      .addGroupBy('tags.id')
      .addGroupBy('tags.keyword')
      .addGroupBy('writer.id')
      .addGroupBy('writer.name')
      .select([
        'writer.id',
        'writer.name',
        'tags.id',
        'tags.keyword',
        'card.id',
        'card.title',
        'card.content',
        'card.isAnonymity',
        'card.isAnswered',
        'COUNT(pickers.id) AS pickersCount',
      ])
      .getMany();


